# kotlin compareBy using IntArray, how do I get the 'a' and 'b' fields?

Tags: kotlin, generics, priority-queue

new to kotlin and struggle with the syntax of compareBy and its lambda to get the 'a' and 'b' parameters for a custom compare:

```
public inline fun <T> compareBy(crossinline selector: (T) -> Comparable<*>?): Comparator<T> =
    Comparator { a, b -> compareValuesBy(a, b, selector) }
```

Basically I want to compare 2d points that are stored as IntArray(x,y) but don't know how to access the a and b elements of the declaration. Here where I am stuck:

```
val compareByDistance: Comparator<IntArray> = compareBy {
    // b - a to origin = (bx2 - 0)^2 - (by2 - 0)^2 -> no need square root
    val distance = -1
    distance
}

val points = PriorityQueue<IntArray>(compareByDistance)
points.add(intArrayOf(1, 2))
points.add(intArrayOf(2, 3))
```

when I run the debugger I see the 'a' and 'b' parameters, but I have to idea how to access them.

[image]

If I do:

```
val k = it.first()
```

it does not give k = a = [2,3] just k =2, but still I can't access b.

What is the correct syntax for the lambda? I looked in this thread by did not help:

https://www.bezkoder.com/kotlin-priority-queue/

thank you.

Comment: Frankly, I have problems understanding what is your expected sorting order. If you need both compared items in your lambda, then don't use `compareBy()`, but create a Comparator directly: `val compareByDistance: Comparator<IntArray> = Comparator { a, b -> -1 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
   val compareByDistance = Comparator<IntArray> { a:IntArray, b:IntArray ->
            // Return -1 , +1 ,0 - Based on your Formula
            0
        }
```

Here in your code , when you see `compareBy` will be accepting lambda of type `Comparable<T>` which has only one parameter.
It will only return default `Comparator`.

The solution is to create object for `Comparator` Interface like above . In which compare has two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming from the formula you have in your code comment that you are wanting to compare your points by their distance from the origin (0, 0).

The `compareBy` lambda has a single parameter since you use it to convert each individual IntArray into a number that will be used to compare it to other IntArrays.

When a lambda has a single parameter and you leave it blank like in your code above, it has the implicit name `it`, so you could use `it[0]` and `it[1]` for *a* and *b*. But you can name it using a [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html) to conveniently get named *a* and *b* variables.

```
val compareByDistance: Comparator<IntArray> = compareBy { (a, b) ->
    a * a + b * b
}
```

Comment: no this is giving me the same thing notice that a and b are arrays or two integers. So a = [2,3] and b = [1,2], so using as written makes a = 2 and b =3. The answer with above is the correct one. But thank you.

Comment: @gmmo if all you need is to sort these by distance from origin this is the simpler way to do it. Comparator’s constructor is for more complicated situations where you need both elements at once to be able to figure out how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look at the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) again:

```
fun <T> compareBy(
    vararg selectors: (T) -> Comparable<*>?
): Comparator<T>
```

> Creates a comparator using the sequence of functions to calculate a result of comparison. The functions are called sequentially, receive the given values `a` and `b` and return `Comparable` objects. As soon as the `Comparable` instances returned by a function for `a` and `b` values do not compare as equal, the result of that comparison is returned from the `Comparator`.

And also the info for [`Comparator`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/) which is what that function is ultimately producing:

```
abstract fun compare(a: T, b: T): Int
```

---

So what's basically happening is, a `Comparator` has a `compare` function which takes two values that it's going to compare - these are named `a` and `b`. They're probably the parameters you're seeing in the debugger, when the comparison is actually running.

The `compareBy` function on the other hand, takes one or more *selector* functions which transform each item you want to compare into *some value* for comparison.

```
compareBy(
    { it.length }
}
```

That one's fairly simple - that function is run on every item to produce a length value. *That* is what gets passed into the `compare` function, the value returned for two of the items, and those two values are called `a` and `b` in the comparison.

So the functions you provide to `compareBy` act on **one item**. They just transform an item into a value for comparison purposes - or, if you provide multiple functions, they transform an item into several values for several comparison steps. You're not doing any actual comparison here, so there's no concept of another item, `a` and `b`. Just different representations of a single item.

---

So in your example, each item is a 2-element array, right? That's just a single item, and you just need to transform it into a value for comparison - in this case, a distance.

```
// skipping the parentheses since it's one selector function
compareBy { myArray ->
    // evaluate to the value we want to "return"
    val x = myArray[0]
    val y = myArray[1]
    // I think this is what you meant? This gives you distance-squared
    (x * x) + (y * y)
}
```

This gives you a `Comparator` that, *for whatever items you give its `compare` function*, calculates the distance-squared for each and compares them based on *that*. That's where the `a` and `b` come into it - comparing separate items, and at that part you're not involved. The work you do is setting up *how to see an item that's being compared* and then feeding a bunch of items into it and letting it run

Comment: no, @Gowthan KK answer in the only one correct. There are two array elements  a = [2,3] and b = [1,2], I need to compare the two array elements and *NOT* the elements of one array. x and y in your case will give me x=1, y=2, I need x = [2,3] and y = [1,2]. But thx.

Comment: @gmmo well however you want to compare them - the point is that this is how `compareBy` works, it transforms a single item (e.g. a single array) into a *comparable value*, and that's what the `Comparator` uses when comparing items. If you want to compare the items directly, you don't need `compareBy` to generate a `Comparator` for you - you just write the `Comparator` yourself. `compareBy` is a tool to make comparison easier, but it's not appropriate for every situation. I'm just trying to help you understand how it works and why you were having trouble with it

Comment: I truly appreciate your time and help. I didn't put all the information so the thread would not get long. The story behind is to solve the leetcode problem (973. K Closest Points to Origin) in kotlin. If you look the way the want the parameters and outputs (select the kotlin opion), they make all x,y as single array of 2 elements a[0] = x, a[1]=y. Honestly, I don't like it at all, it would be much cleaner to use a data class Pos {val x:Int, val y:Int) or something like that. But I have write the code as they want, so this is why I got stuck on the comparator.

Comment: @gmmo it's not really the specific implementation though - you need a `Comparator` to compare pairs of objects, and its `compare` method is where you describe how to compare `a` and `b`. You can just create a `Comparator` object like that, like in Gowtham's anwer - if that's what you need, great! `compareBy` is a utility that will generate that `Comparator` *for you*, using functions you include to transform `a` and `b` into other values, and doing standard comparison on those. But that won't work for you, since you need `a` and `b` as they are so you can poke at them and use special logic

Comment: Basically because you need access to `a` and `b`, you need to write the `Comparator` directly. Trying to use `compareBy` was giving you problems because it doesn't work that way - in there, you're defining code that works on *one* object, transforming it into another value. There's no *compare `a` and `b`* logic in there - so you were looking at the wrong thing, if you get me. It works for my example (transforming your `x` and `y` into a single distance value, which can be compared) but not for what you want to do. Just trying to make sure you get why it was tripping you up!